# Upgrade AKS node without changing Pods CIDR

Tags: azure, azure-aks

Is there a way to upgrade a cluster without changing the Pods CIDR, or to somehow reset it afterward?
My cluster only has one node, and it had the pod CIDR 10.244.0.0/24. I did an upgrade to change the Kubernetes version, and now it's 10.244.1.0/24. Is there a way to go back to 10.244.0.0/24?

It's important to me because I am using the subnet and the cluster IP as configurations for an external site 2 site VPN and I can't change the remote configurations anytime I need to perform an upgrade.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deploy your cluster using an ARM template you can specify the Pod CIDR value using the `podCidr` property of the `networkProfile` which is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters?tabs=json#containerservicenetworkprofile-object).  Unfortunately it's not possible to set that value when deploying via the Azure Portal.

There's an example of an ARM template that implements that property [here](https://github.com/NickGraham101/dfc-devops/blob/master/ArmTemplates/aks.json), that template also allows you to pass in the Kubernetes version so you can upgrade simply by redeploying the ARM template.  I'm not sure what would happen if you fixed the Pod CIDR using the template but upgraded Kubernetes via the portal.

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually provisioning my infrastructure through terraform and your answer led me to the solution. I found this parameter here -> https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#pod_cidr